# Background-size cover to img tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

html

```
<div>
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapersplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg" />
</div>
```

css

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
img{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Why background-size: cover doesn't work here. This should also be added in css3, but not added. Is there anyway not to stretch the image?

As we can do it with `background: url("http://www.hdwallpapersplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg") no-repeat; background-size: cover;`

Comment: The background-size property specifies the size of the background image. So if you set background image to div, and set this property then it will work. Here for <img>, there is no any background image set.

Comment: Are you expecting the **foreground** image to be affected by the **background** styling? Sorry, that's just not how it works.

Comment: the background size property does not apply to an image

Comment: @Spudley does it work : foreground image?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar: the image that you specify in `<img src=''>` is a **foreground** image; it is the content of the `img` element. It is **not** a background image and will not react to CSS background styling. You can set the background image in CSS as normal, just like any other element (it will show through any transparent bits of the foreground image), and *that* background image can be styled using `background-size`. You mentioned you could do this at the end of the question; if you want to use `background-size` styling, that is how you must do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry! You can do this too using jQuery!

```
var imgSrc=$('div img').attr('src');

$('div img').remove();
$('div').html('<div class="backbg"></div>');
$('.backbg').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgSrc + ')');
$('.backbg').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
$('.backbg').css('background-size','cover');
$('.backbg').css('width','100%');
$('.backbg').css('height','100%');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9g442/1/)

Comment: FWIW: You can do the above in css alone. (Take a look at my answer)

Comment: You can but you should try to avoid javascript if possible.

Comment: For the love of reason, do not use this mess.

Answer (score 14):

### Solution #1 - The new object-fit property ([Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit))

Just set `object-fit: cover;` on the img .

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapersplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg" />
```

You can read more about this new property in this [webplatform article](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/object-fit).

From the above article - regarding the 'cover' value:

> The whole image is scaled down or expanded till  it fills the box
>   completely, the aspect ratio is  maintained. This normally results in
>   only part of the image being visible.

Also, here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/n8qxcp4b/1/) from the above article which demonstrates all the values of the `object-fit` property.

### Solution #2 - Replace the img with a background image with  css

```css
img {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  background: url(http://www.hdwallpapersplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapersplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg" />
```

Comment: Whilst I'd like to say either of those solutions are viable, they're not really. Setting a width and height on an img tag as padding values is really hacky, when you look at it from a dev perspective. You'd still have to apply those values with JS if you wanted your image to be responsive or just vary in width/height.

Comment: seems that it's working on FF and Android too... 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: @rorymorris setting the `background-image` `url` is the problem I see. If we only could use `attr(src url)` then we could avoid JS, but sadly no browsers have implemented that spec at the time of writing.

Comment: Solution #1 works great, this should be picked as the answer.