# Background-size cover clipping issue

Tags: css, responsive-images

I am using **background-size: cover** property for making a div with background image **responsive**. But it is getting **clipped** which is unwanted. Is there some way I can avoid clipping and also get a responsive image?
I even tried **replacing div** with img tag and used [Background-size cover to img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942081/background-size-cover-to-img-tag) article to make it appear similar. Still the issue prevailed.

Here is the css for div having background image:

```
.slides {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("images/image1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Screenshots: After getting clipped (resolution is mentioned above the image)
[image]

Actual image:
[image]

Comment: `background-size: cover` intentionally does clipping, i.e. it assures that the element's area is always covered. What exactly do you want? Have you tried `background-size: contain`? This will keep the whole image inside its element, but might produce empty gaps.

Comment: I want full screen images in slider. So I have used div elements(as slides) having background image. But I need to make this responsive too and that is why I am not using `background-size: 100% 100%` or `background-size: contain` and keeping up with cover.

Comment: So... There will be cases where the image's aspect ratio doesn't fit your elemen't aspect ratio. Unless you want to stretch the image unnaturally, there will be parts cut off or spaces left empty; that's plain simple geometry.

Comment: Oh thanks. I understand but is there any way I can achieve responsive full screen images without it getting clipped? Or at least minimize the clipping?

Comment: `cover` actually minimizes the clipping already, i.e. it proportionally stretches the background image until the element is just covered.

Comment: @BhumikaMakhijaney cover works by perfectly fitting one dimension (width or hide). The other dimension is allowed to overflow and clipped. This is the way it works. Could you please provide an example mockup and the expected output?

Comment: The white area in your screenshot is created by padding, border or margin on one of the parent elements, if it truly was height 100%, width 100% there would be no white border

Comment: Thanks to both of you for providing information. Please can you refer the edit I just made. You can see the clipping is too much to ignore

Comment: @Djave I removed margin and padding. Still the issue prevails. Attached new screenshot in edit

Comment: Oh, right! Please refer to the other answers – background cover is never going to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps - to fully support responsive images, you can use

```
picture
sizes
```

You can choose a different image asset based on the view-port width. Just make the primary subject visible in the stretched down image, and choose this image asset at your desired view-port break-point. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1053341/Responsive-Images-on-the-Web-How-to-build-with-src) covers it in detail.